# Leaflet Routing Machine

Tags: javascript, web, routes, leaflet

i am trying to use the Leaflet Routing Machine to display the route between two points. I have implemented these functions exactly like in the example on the Plugin Provider Website. I get two markers but the way isn't displayed.

```
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <title>Wanderrouten24</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet-routing-machine-3.2.7/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js'></script>
    <script src="leaflet-routing-machine-3.2.7/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 440px; border: 1px solid #AAA;"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='maps/createRoute.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var map = L.map( 'map', {
  center: [20.0, 5.0],
  minZoom: 2,
  zoom: 2
});

L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: [
      L.latLng(49.47748, 8.42216),
      L.latLng(49.47648, 8.32216)
  ],
  routeWhileDragging: true
}).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}).addTo( map );

map.setView([49.47748, 8.42216], 15);

map.locate({setView: true, watch: true}) /* This will return map so you can do chaining */
.on('locationfound', function(e){})
.on('locationerror', function(e){
    console.log(e);
    alert("Location access denied.");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'maneuver' of undefined

since [`leaflet-routing-machine` library](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/issues/444) is not compatible with `leaflet v0.7.7`, [here](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/issues/444) is a similar reported issue.

So, the solution would be to upgrade `leaflet` to version `1.0.0` or above, once updated the route should be printed as expected, [here is a demo](https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/EdRRwr?editors=1111)